# Git: fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists

Tags: git

I want to To checkout branch which not exists locally but is in the remote repo

```
>git checkout -t -b master origin/master
fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.
```

and when I browse the git project using a browser I only see a **develop** branch

Comment: Did you try without the `-t` ?

Comment: @NuñitodelaCalzada What's wrong with `git checkout master`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You answer should be : `git checkout master`.